# Error estimation for numeric quadrature on an $n$-simplex

Tags: numerical-integration

I asked this on [Math SE](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/431214/error-estimation-for-numeric-quadrature-on-an-n-simplex) but got no interactions. Thinking for a bit this might be better suited for this site.

Suppose I have a sufficiently nice function from a simplex $S\subseteq\mathbb R^n$ with vertices $(v_0,\dotsc,v_n)$ to $\mathbb R$, call it $f$. I want to estimate the error when approximating the integral
$$\int_S d^nxf(x)$$
via the generalized trapezoid rule
$$\frac{1}{(n+1)!}\det
\begin{pmatrix} v_0&\cdots&v_n\\\ 1&\cdots&1\end{pmatrix}\sum\limits_{i=0}^n f(v_i).$$

Wikipedia gives a bound for the $n=1$ case [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule), but I tried quite a bit and the derivation doesn't seem to generalize well. I need suggestions on strategies to estimate the error. A loose bound would be enough, all I need is to understand on what power of the volume, or equivalently what orders of derivatives of $f$ the error scales with.